# How to mix textured and untextured polygons?

Tags: directx, textures, texture-mapping

I'd like to apply textures to my polygons but only to some i.e. have to vertex formats one that is coord+color, and one that is coord+texcoord

My understanding is that you can only have one vertex buffer format per pass/Draw/InputHandler?

does this mean having to have two Draw invocations? (is calling Draw multiple times per frame a bad thing? I could see myself having to call it up to 10-20 times per frame with my current understanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you can only use one vertex-format for one Draw-Call. You could merge them, i.e. to a (Position,Color,Texcoord)-Format and branch in the shader, but this wouldn't be faster. It is normal to have multiple Draw-Calls per Frame, some sources say you shouldn't use more then 500 Draw-Calls, but there is no real limit. Each Draw-Call introduce some overhead and batching is sometimes very useful.